# Align object's orientation -rotation, transform, and scale to another object's orientation

Tags: snapping, transform-orientation

I am using 2.8 and am wondering how do you align or snap an object's orientation to another object's orientation that has a different location, rotation, and scale- in a quick tool like way such as 3ds Max's align tool? -I know I can copy the transform values, and 'snap cursor to selected'->'snap selection to cursor' does not snap the rotation or scale values. Is there a script or current tool that will do this without much process? - thx.

Comment: Do you mean something like the copy rotation and copy location and copy scale modifier?

Answer (score 6):

Yeah that exists in Blender 2.8 as well as in 2.7.

Just select the object or objects you want to apply the rotation to first (press shift to select multiple objects). 
Then also select the object you want to copy the rotation from at the very last. 
Then open the Properties Region (menue on the right side , shortcut [n]).
There you hover over the rotation or location or scale and click the right mouse button. Then you select 'copy all to selected'. You can also only copy the one value you hover over by selecting 'copy single to selected'.
[image]

Comment: Thanks guys! -That works. - -